# The simplest possible req.body is always empty

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm just trying to pass the simplest data possible (at the moment, for test purposes) from client to server with a POST request, but I keep getting empty or undefined logs on req.body.

Server:

```
//jshint esversion:6

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/sandbox", {useNewUrlParser: true});

app.get("/", function(req, res){

  res.render("home", {});

})

app.post("/filter", function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body);
  res.redirect("/");
})

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

Client (version 1):

```
var yourdata = { "name": "The pertinent data"};
console.log(document.body)
    $.ajax({
      url : "/filter",
      type: "POST",
      dataType:'text',
      data : yourdata,
      contentType: "application/json",
  });
```

Client (version 2):

```
var payload = {data: "The pertinent data"};
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('POST', '/filter' , true);
req.send(JSON.stringify(payload))
```

I added both attempts at a code client-side, but I'm happy with whichever method works. Ideally I'll eventually tap into the payload or data with req.body.payload or something, but at the moment that's just giving me an undefined.

I've looked into quite a few similar posts and usually they were missing the "app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));" or "app.use(bodyParser.json());" I've tried adding and removing those, changing from true to false, still empty.

The console.log(document.body) on the client script does work, giving me the expected body on the browser console, and the server route is working too, eventually redirecting to home.

I can't see how the issue is something I'm doing wrong on the client side, but oddly enough, if I create a form, with an action to that route, and submit, it seems to send the req.body normally. E.g.:

```
<form class="form" action="/filter" method="post">
  <input name="newName" placeholder="Name">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

That does indeed log a JSON object e.g.: { newName: 'John'}

In case it might be relevant, the HTML is the simplest one possible, almost empty, only really doing the pertinent links.

Thanks all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need three things:

1. A request body encoded in some data format
2. A content-type request header which says which data format you are using
3. Body parsing middleware that can process that data format

---

When you submit a form, with no `enctype` attribute, it will submit the data in URL encoded format with the right content type. This matches the body parsing middleware you have (`bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})`).

1, 2, and 3 are all good.

Note that it **does not** create a JSON object. The client produces URL encoded data. The server parses that into a JavaScript object. [There is no JSON](https://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

---

> Client (version 1):

Here you are passing an object to jQuery so it will URL encode the data in it and would normally set the correct content type.

It is failing because you have `contentType: "application/json",`.

Since you are falsely claiming that you are sending JSON, `bodyParser.urlencoded` ignores it.

If you had a JSON body parser in place, it would error because the data is not JSON.

1 and 3 are good, but 2 is a lie.

**Remove the `contentType` property**.

---

> Client (version 2):

Now you are JSON encoding the data, but you aren't setting the content type request header, and you don't have body parsing middleware that can handle JSON.

3 is bad, and either 1 or 2 is too.

Comment: Tested your solution for Client (version 1) and it's working as intended. Linked article is useful too.

Answer (score 0):

For the server-side part of your application, you need something that moves the body of the request out of the request string itself to a clear, easy-to-read, and use variable. The express `json()` method (*middleware*) does that exactly.

Use the express JSON parser middleware as follows:

```js
app.use(express.json())
```

Code:

```js
const express = require("express");
// const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json()); //  here
// ... the rest of your code
```

Just few notes about the middleware you're using

```js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

- We usually use this middleware to parse the HTML forms data, in other words, it's just like the express middleware `express.json()`, but the difference here is that it parses the requests which have the content type of HTML forms, while the `express.json()` converts the ones which have the content-type of `application/json`.
- If you're using express v +4, you don't need the bodyParser package, express has the .`urlencoded()` and the `.json()` methods built into the express package itself, you can use them just as `express.json()` and `express.urlencoded()`.

Tip, you can have both middlewares, the JSON parser, and the HTML form content type parser, when the server receives a content-type JSON, the express.json() middleware will parse the request body, and if the server receives an HTML form content-type the urlencoded middleware will fire:

code example:

```js
const express = require("express");
// const bodyParser = require("body-parser"); ❌ not needed
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json()); //  here
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })) //  here
// ... the rest of your code
```

Comment: Adding that middleware is insufficient since neither of the JavaScript examples are sending JSON with an application/json content-type header.

Comment: @Quentin, not sure if misunderstood the question, but obviously the server-side is missing a JSON parser and the client-side code #1 seems correct to me, let me read the OP question again

Comment: Example 1 passes an object to `data` so jQuery will URL encode it, not JSON encode it. The body parsing middleware then doesn't try to parse it because the content-type header lies.